# How to use IFileOperation with relative and absolute paths?

Tags: winapi, com, windows-shell

What is the `IFileOperation` equivalent of

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCTW op = {hDlg, FO_COPY, directoryFrom, directoryTo, 0, FALSE, NULL, NULL};
int status = SHFileOperationW(&op);
```

where `directoryFrom` is a directory path relative to my working directory and `directoryTo` is absolute?

1. May I directly pass my absolute path to `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` to get an `IShellItem`? What are parsing names and display names, anyway?
2. If `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` is appropriate for absolute paths, should I use it in conjunction with `GetFullPathNameW` to resolve the relative path or is there a simpler alternative?

I am finding the documentation on those topics could be much better.

Comment: `IFileOperation` works on `IShellItem` interfaces. You can't create an `IShellItem` for a relative path by itself, only for an absolute path. It is not that hard to create an absolute path by using `GetCurrentDirectory()` or equivalent and then appending your relative path to it.  Otherwise, you can get an `IShellItem` for your working directory first, and then use `SHCreateItemFromRelativeName()` to create an `IShellItem` for a path relative to the working directory.  But really, you shouldn't be relying on the working directory to begin with. Always use absolute paths.

Comment: A Shell Item does not always correspond to a physical file. Hence the need for IFileDialog which supports virtual items. A Shell Item's parsing name is supposed to be unique in a parent Shell Folder, and is used to get IShellItem. A display name is used for display only and can be ambiguous (two items can have the same display name in a given Shell Folder). For physical file or folders, parsing and display names are the same. SHCreateItemFromParsingName  works fine with absolute path for physical files and folders.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought about using `SHCreateItemFromRelativeName`, too, thank you for confirming that it should work. While I could maybe do away with working directories to solve my current problem I would still argue that working directories are invaluable and simplify a lot of things - although they should probably not be changeable in my opinion.

Comment: @SimonMourier That would explain why `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` might _work_ with display names but the official documentation makes it needlessly confusing by specifying it to work _only_ with display names without any explanation. Still, I don't quite understand your distinction between physical and non-physical files and folders and how they interact with parsing and display names. Am I correct in assuming that a physical file or folder would be one that actually exists in the file system? Does `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` not work then for nonexistent paths?

Comment: If you could write up a detailed explanation on those paths and names and their relationship to shelll items and the `SHCreateItem...` functions I would accept that as an answer as this is the point I am struggling most with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Shell is organized into a hierarchy called the Shell *namespace*: [Introduction to the Shell Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro):

> The Shell namespace organizes the file system and other objects
> managed by the Shell into a single tree-structured hierarchy.
> Conceptually, it is a larger and more inclusive version of the file
> system.

What it means is, in the Shell Namespace, there are file system (or what I call "physical", considering possible kernel file systems as physical too) items and virtual items. Example of virtual items are:

- The "This PC" folder
- The Recycle Bin (where item have links into the file system)
- The Control Panel (fully virtual)
- Search folders  (where items are links into other items)
- Custom namespace extensions (you can [extend the Shell namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-works) with a custom Shell Namespace Extension to connect to a database, a cloud storage, etc.)
- etc.

All these items are identified using the same system: [PIDLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro#item-id-lists). A *PIDL* is to a Shell Item what a full file path is to a (physical) file or folder.

Items can also be identified using their Parsing Name which is indirectly defined by [IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-getdisplaynameof) and by [_SHGDNF enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-_shgdnf), if the containing folder supports it. Note a *PIDL* is strictly mandatory (each item has one) while a parsing name is not.

Since Windows Vista, it's recommended to use `IShellItem`-based API. And `IFileDialog` is also recommended because it supports PIDLs (=> virtual items), not only file system paths.

The pseudo code for `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` is more or less:

1. call `SHParseDisplayName(name)` => a PIDL (old PIDL-based API)
2. call `SHCreateItemFromIDList(pidl)` => an IShellItem

Which indeed proves that `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` could have been called `SHCreateItemFromDisplayName`...

Internally, `SHParseDisplayName`'s code is more or less:

1. get desktop's `IShellFolder` (desktop is the root of the Shell's namespace)
2. call `IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName`(name) => a PIDL (relative to desktop which is the same as absolute since desktop is the namespace root)

`IShellFolder` is the interface implemented by *all* namespace folders: standard Windows-provided ones and custom ones, serving file system items or virtual items.

Now, `IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName` implementation vary. A custom Shell Folder can choose to implement it the way it likes (which can cause issues).

However desktop's `IShellFolder` implementation is quite complex and understands file system paths in lieu of *display name*. The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-parsedisplayname) says this:

> A null-terminated Unicode string with the display name. Because each
> Shell folder defines its own parsing syntax, the form this string can
> take may vary. The desktop folder, for instance, accepts paths such as
> "C:\My Docs\My File.txt". It also will accept references to items in
> the namespace that have a GUID associated with them using the
> "::{GUID}" syntax. For example, to retrieve a fully qualified
> identifier list for the control panel from the desktop folder, you can
> use the following:
>
> ::{CLSID for Control Panel}\::{CLSID for printers folder}

Comment: Thank you for this detailed writeup. However, I am still uncertain where display names and parsing names are distinct from each other. For example, I should be able to pass ::{CLSID for Control Panel}\::{CLSID for printers folder} to `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` or `SHParseDisplayName`, right? But then, parsing name and display name are the same thing again? Could you provide an example where those two actually differ?

Comment: @purefanatic - if you read carefully including the links, you should be able to understand. You won't find much more explanation I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I read everything and am a little smarter now. I think most of my confusion came from the fact that display names and parsing names are not considered disjoint: parsing names are more like a subset of display names, i.e. those display names that can be successfully parsed by `IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName` etc.. Only then it makes sense in my opinion. I feel like this could have been clearer in your answer text. The `_SHGDNF` documentation has helped me most as it comes up with actual examples. The shell namespace extension read was rather unrelated.

Comment: @purefanatic - You can only understand how IShellFolder really works when you write a namespace extension. All IShellFolder implementations are somewhat "extensions". Even the built-in ones.